# MS Access backend table access locks entire backend file Office 365

Tags: ms-access, database-locking

Background:
We currently run a large set of MS Access databases (I know, they should be migrated, but the business won't spend the money) with a central fileserver location for backend files and front end files running on each users' computers; it is a many to many linking of front and backend databases. Users are currently running Windows 10 Enterprise build 10.0.19042. All users have full control in the file location in which the backend databases are stored. All frontend databases are accde files that are set to have default file locking to "No Lock". 
Problem:
We recently (within the last week) started seeing instances where opening a backend table, whether to query it or make a change, is locking the entire backend file. Previously we would regularly have multiple users editing rows in the same table simultaneously. We have tried moving the network location, adding and subtracting user permissions, restoring file backups, and changing default file locking to the 6 combinations that can be achieved on 2 computers. Does anyone have any idea where this is coming from or how to remove this locking behavior?

Comment: What is total file size of these Access databases? SQLServerExpress allows 10GB and is free. So is SQL Server Management Studio to manage design. I was able to install both on my laptop as a single user setup. Retained Access as frontend.

Comment: Note please, that the issue persists for shared _DFS_ paths. If so, for a workaround, use a UNC path to a specified server member.